# Error: Step implementation missing for the second feature file

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cucumber, integration-testing, cypress

I've created some Cucumber scenarios in a feature file using Cypress. If I'm correct, the feature file and the spec file should be under the same folder. When I run the tests with the test runner, everything works fine. But I've created a second feature with the same scenarios and I receive this error "Error: Step implementation missing for" when I try to run it.

Bellow I attached few screenshots:

[image]
[image]

```
// cypress > integration > cucumber-test > login.feature
Feature: Login Feature

Scenario: 1. Login Validation

Given I am in the Swag labs login page
When I enter valid credentials
Then I should be able to login successfully


Scenario: 2. Login Validation part 2

Given I am in the Swag labs login page
When I enter valid credentials
Then I should be able to login successfully

Scenario: 3. Login Validation part 3

Given I am in the Swag labs login page
When I enter valid credentials
Then I should be able to login successfully
```

Answer (score 3):

> Step implementation missing

As DavidZ mentioned, this error means that Cucumber can't find the step it is looking for. This can happen for a number of reasons.

### Solution #1

The step file has to be under a folder with the the same name as the `.feature` file. For example,

```
- myScenario
  |
  - stepFile.js
- myScenario.feature
```

is a valid file structure, but

```
- myScenario1
  |
  - stepFile.js
- myScenario.feature
```

is not a valid file structure.

### Solution #2

The step file has to contain a method with the same name as the step Cucumber is looking for. These have to match exactly.

Your `login.feature` file has the step `Given I am in the Swag labs login page`. Cucumber is looking for a step like

```
Given('I am in the Swag labs login page', () => {
    // Step implementation...
});
```

that starts with the keyword `Given` and the first parameter matches the remainder of the step *exactly*.

Note: There are slight variations of the above solutions depending on your IDE/text editor. For more information, see IDE Support in the `README.md` of [cypress-cucumber-preprocessor](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor)

Comment: Answer 1 is perfect, I had the same problem and it worked

Answer (score -1):

one question... When you say

> the feature file and the spec file should be under the same folder

where did you read that? The feature files (BDD like) replace the spec files, so you either work with feature files or spec files. As you can experience you can actually have all of them, but in the correct setup for the Cucumber plugin, you'd work with just the feature files :)

```
{
  "testFiles": "**/*.feature"
}
```

---

About the error reported there, it means that the feature file cannot find the step that you wrote in the scenario in the `step_definitions` directory.

In my case I have them under `cypress/support/step_definitions`.

Make sure that you can find `I am in the Swag Labs login page` in any of the step definitions file.

Also you can find here all the help you might need https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor